# Trouble locating Angular element for Protractor UI Nav test

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to select the third option in a dropdown list.  Below are some details about the element:

Outer HTML:

```
<md-option _ngcontent-c6="" role="option" ng-reflect-value="last90Days" tabindex="0" id="md-option-2" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--> Last 90 Days <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" md-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"> </div> </md-option>
```

CSS Selector:

```
#md-option-37 > div:nth-child(1)
```

Sorry for the terrible formatting.  If anyone has any suggestions about how to select the "Last 90 Days" dropdown item then I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand out of your info an the AngularJS `md-select` you need to do the following

```js
// Open the md-select, use the correct selector, this is a demo
$('md-select').click();

// There is an animation, I don't know how long, you need to wait for the animation to be finished. 
// Quick and dirty is a browser.sleep(), but it's better to find a more stable way because if the animation will take longer in the future your test will break
browser.sleep(500);

// Click on you option, this can be done in several ways

// By index
$$('md-option').get(1).click();
// By text
element(by.cssContainingText('md-option', 'your text')).click();

// Wait for the menu to close, this is also an animation
browser.sleep(500);
```

For `element(by.css('selector'));` I always use the [shorthand notation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$), for the rest of the selectors see the [docs of Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api).

I would advice to use a better way to wait for the animation to be done. Here I used a `browser.sleep()`, but it's not future proof. You don't want your script to rely on sleeps.

Hope it helps.