# How to select an option with Angular Material 2 and Protractor?

Tags: angular, angular-material, protractor

I'm writing some e2e tests with protractor. My application is an Angular Material 2 application. In my test I want to select an option of a md-select by value. When I inspect the open md-select I see the md-option items. The values of the options are in an attribute ng-reflect-value.

Let's say I have an option with the value "optionA". How can I select a certain option by this value?

I tried this:

```
element(by.name('myselect')).click();
$$('.mat-option').then((options) => {
  ...
});
```

and inside then I see the correct number of options, but how can I select the option which has the value "opetionA" ?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to select an option based on a non-visible value for a customer during E2E tests? Isn't it better to use the visible value, this is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073870/trouble-locating-angular-element-for-protractor-ui-nav-test/44089777#44089777) answer

Comment: Yes, you're right. That might be the better solution.

Answer (score 7):

This example is a bit crude, but it shows how to do what you want:

html:

```
<mat-form-field id="your-id">
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option [value]="1">1</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="2">2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
function selectOptionByOptionValue(selectFormFieldElementId, valueToFind) {

  const formField = element(by.id(selectFormFieldElementId));
  formField.click().then(() => {

    formField.element(by.tagName('mat-select'))
      .getAttribute('aria-owns').then((optionIdsString: string) => {
        const optionIds = optionIdsString.split(' ');    

        for (let optionId of optionIds) {
          const option = element(by.id(optionId));
          option.getText().then((text) => {
            if (text === valueToFind) {
              option.click();
            }
          });
        }
      });
  });
}

selectOptionByOptionValue('your-id', '1');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent and very helpful. I faced some challenge inside the if loop, suggesting an edit if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is make your css-selector "dynamic" by adding the expected value in the selector. For example

```js
// I've place the expected value in a var to make it more clear
const optionValue = 'your-option-value';

// Open select
element(by.name('myselect')).click();
// Click on the option with your selected value
$(`.mat-option[value="${optionValue}"]`).click();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: value is not an attribute of a <md-option> in Angular Material 2. But this works for me:
$('.mat-option[ng-reflect-value="optionA"]').click();

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
    element.all(by.cssContainingText('span.mat-option-text', "option text to search for")).click();
```

Got answer from this question: [How to locate element by span value in protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578333/how-to-locate-element-by-span-value-in-protractor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)