# How to locate element by span value in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have a drop down box and I want to locate element by span value. How to do this? I don't want to use xpath as it is not a best practice.

[image]

Comment: Does the span value here mean the text content displayed between span tag?  If so, you have to use xpath, because css selector not support to find element by its text content.

Comment: yes. <span class="mat-option-text">100</span>. here i want to use 100. only this value is unique here.

Comment: There is an id attribute. Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
element(by.cssContainingText('span.mat-option-text', '100'))
```

**Option 2**

```
element(by.xpath('//span[@class="mat-option-text"][text()="100"]'))
```