# Cypress e2e test with Angular Material mat-select can't set a select value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, cypress, angular9

I am trying to set a `mat-option` value with a Cypress test in Angular 9. I have tried all of the following workarounds below and none of them works. I am using Angular Material and the `mat-select` component with dynamic `ngFor` `mat-options`. The selector works fine but I can't set it or get the click to work correctly on the `mat-select`.

Example `mat-select` I am using

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Begin Year</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="beginYear" data-cy="beginYear-select">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let year of beginYearOptions" [value]="year">
        {{ year }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

failed attempts to get the click set

```
cy.get('[data-cy=beginYear-select]')
  .contains(yearValue.toString())
  .click();
```

or

```
cy.get('mat-select')
  .first()
  .click({ force: true })
  .get('mat-option')
  .contains(yearValue.toString())
  .click()
```

or

```
cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="beginYear"]')
  .first()
  .click()
  .get('mat-option')
  .contains(yearValue.toString())
  .click();
```

or

```
cy.get('mat-select[formcontrolname="beginYear"]').then(() => {
  cy.get('mat-option')
    .contains(endYear.toString())
    .click();
})
```

or

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selectMaterialDropDown', (formControlName, selectOption) => {
  cy.get(`[formcontrolname="${formControlName}"]`).click().then(() => {
    cy.get(`.cdk-overlay-container .mat-select-panel .mat-option-text`).should('contain', selectOption);
    console.log('PASSED!!!')
    cy.get(`.cdk-overlay-container .mat-select-panel .mat-option-text:contains("${selectOption}")`).first().click().then(() => {
      // After click, mat-select should contain the text of the selected option
      cy.get(`[formcontrolname="${formControlName}"]`).contains(selectOption);
    });
  });
});
```

None of these worked and basically threw an error saying `mat-option` can't be found. Most of the time the `mat-select` popup did not even appear after the click event. I have also tried adding wait calls to see if it was an async issue but the same thing happened. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have attached some references below that I have also tried. I am confused why the popup does not appear consistently from `mat-select` on a click event and if it does it can't find any options.

REFERENCES:

- [Make selection using cypress in Angular if you're using material forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699684/make-selection-using-cypress-in-angular-if-youre-using-material-forms)
- [select dropdownlist item using cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362422/select-dropdownlist-item-using-cyp)
- [How to select an option with Angular Material 2 and Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234895/how-to-select-an-option-with-angular-material-2-and-protractor)
- [Cypress: Test if element does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915773/cypress-test-if-element-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue and had to get around it like this:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=beginYear-select]')
  .click()
  .get('mat-option')
  .contains('2021')
  .click();
cy.get('body').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cy.get('mat-select[data-cy="beginYear-select"]')
  .contains(yearValue.toString())
  .click();
```

If it doesn't work try to remove `"-"` in the identifier: `beginYearSelect`

Answer (score 0):

Material Select has all options in CDK overlay, therefore:

```
//open select
cy.get('mat-select').click();

//locale options and click on option
cy.root().closest('.cdk-overlay-container').within(() => {
          cy.get('selector-for-mat-option').click();
        });
```

that cy.root() is helpful in case you have your commands within something like `cy.get('form').within(() => { //all form commands here })`  because it will help you to escape back to root of DOM to locale CDK overlay.

Comment: Finding cdk not really necessary, since only one can be present at any time. `cy.get('mat-option')` still seems best way.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to pass '#' before mat-select to properly select it by it's id. Every mat-select is like a input, so in most cases it will be something like "mat-select-1", "mat-select-2"... and so on. I made it work by first clicking my mat-select than clicking an option from that select.

```
cy.get('#mat-select-1').click()
cy.get('#mat-option-2').click()
```

Althrough I just didn't make it work with select() from cypress, this was a workaround.

Comment: How the ids are given internally on material side should not influence e2e tests.